# Can all BMS have their load and charge ports connected together?

Tags: batteries, bms, lifepo4

I bought this e-scooter LiFePo4 battery that comes with separate charge and load ports.

[image: LifePo4 Scooter Battery]

My goal was to then connect them together so I end up with only 2 wires and the battery will get into charge or discharge mode based on voltage of the whole circuit.

Just to confirm this can be done I emailed the seller who answered this:

> This operation is not allowed. Our battery charging and discharging wires are not consistent, and this wire is connected to the structure inside the battery. Please do not attempt to modify or disassemble the battery for reassembly, as this will damage the battery.

Based on this my impression is that they may not fully understand how their BMS works and I'm not totally convinced that they are correct.

So this leads us to my question:
Can all BMS have their charge and load ports connected together? (at least provided I don't charge at higher current than the wire can take. But even if I did, wouldn't the BMS stop or limit that?)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably protection present on the load wires which isn't on the charge wires, and vice versa. Also, charger ports typically don't connect directly to the battery, there is charging circuitry inside the BMS, which makes charging safe. You risk overcharging the battery if you charge via the LOAD port, and you probably won't be able to draw much current from the CHARGE port.

Don't connect the charge and load wires!